# Solution to Recurrence Relation

Tags: recurrence-relations

I asked a question previously, about how to describe

$$
f(n) = n^3
$$

As a recurrence relation. I was, quite rightly, given $a_1=1$ and $a_{n+1}=a_n+3n^2+3n+1$.

I have attempted to solve it, using forward substitution, but I'm having trouble.

I started out by assuming a solution to this recurrence relation was $n^3$. I then attempted a proof by induction that $a_n + 2 = (n+1)^3$

And now I am stuck out of my mind! Can anyone help me out here?

Comment: What kind of arecurrence relation you are looking for?

Comment: If $a_{n+2}=(n+1)^3$, you've gone wrong. You want $a_{n+1}=(n+1)^3$.

Comment: (I'm assuming you meant $a_{n+2}$ rather than $a_n+2$.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$a_{n+1}=(n+1)^3=n^3+3n^2+3n+1=a_n+3n^2+3n+1$$

Comment: How did you go from $(n + 1)^3$ to $n^3 + 3n^2 + 3n + 1$?

Comment: Just expand $(n+1)^3$

Comment: @ChrisCooney or use [Newton's Binomial Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem).

Comment: It should be written exactly backwards for a induction step proof.

Comment: @vonbrand Yeah I got that much :P Sorry, this is really basic but I have gaping holes in my math knowledge! Thankyou for the answer, I will accept in 5 minutes when it lets me.

Comment: @ChrisCooney, check for example the lecture notes by [William Chen](http://rutherglen.science.mq.edu.au/~maths/notes/wchen/ln.html). They cover the "starting university" math very well. Also look at the books by [Trillia](http://www.trillia.com).

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand your question. If you want to show that the solution to the recurrence $$a_{n+1} = a_n + 3n^2 + 3n + 1 \,\,\,\,\, a_1 = 1$$ is $a_n = n^3$, here is a way out.

We have
$$a_{n+1} + n^3 = a_n + \overbrace{n^3 + 3n^2 + 3n + 1}^{(n+1)^3} = a_n + (n+1)^3$$
Now if we call $b_n = a_n - n^3$, we have
$$b_{n+1} = b_n \,\, \text{ and } \,\, b_1 = a_1 - 1 = 0$$
Hence, we get $$b_{n+1} = b_n = b_{n-1} = \cdots = b_1 =0$$
This implies $$a_n = n^3$$

Comment: @user177562 The OP wants to find a recurrence relation for $f(n)=n^3$.

Comment: @GitGud What? ${}$

Comment: I meant I made a mistake when typing your name on the comment above.

Comment: @GitGud I think he said he already had the recurrence, he wanted to find out how to show it worked